# How to check device orientation to change navigator on react native

Tags: react-native

I want to use orientation to change the navigator but it's not working

```
_orientationDidChange: function(orientation) {
    if(orientation == 'LANDSCAPE'){
       navigator.push({ name: 'test' });
    }
}
```

This always gives me an error.

Comment: Could you please add the error?

Comment: Are you using this library: https://github.com/yamill/react-native-orientation ?

Comment: yes i am using github.com/yamill/react-native-orientation

Comment: @MrMush error was "navigator.push not define"